# How can I fix my SQLite query in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, sqlite

I try to create a datagridview query. But I have some syntax error on SQLite and 
I don't know how to fix my query.

```
        string command3 = "";
        for (int y = year1; y <= year2; y++)
        {
            if (y > year1)
            {
                command3 += " UNION ";
            }
            command3 += "SELECT 'Въведени' AS 'Въведени/Изчислени', Station AS '№ на станция', strftime('%Y',Dat) AS 'Година', 'НМ' AS 'НМ/СР/НГ', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=01) AS 'Януари', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=02) AS 'Февруари', (SELECT vkolmin  FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=03) AS 'Март', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " strftime('%m',Dat)=04) AS 'Април', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=05) AS 'Май', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=06) AS 'Юни', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=07) AS 'Юли', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=08) AS 'Август', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=09) AS 'Септември', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=10) AS 'Октомври', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=11) AS 'Ноември', (SELECT vkolmin FROM hydmes WHERE Station= '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat)=12) AS 'Декември'"
            + "FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y
            + "  UNION"
            + "  SELECT 'Изчислени', Station, strftime('%Y',Dat), 'НМ', (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 01 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 02 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 03 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 04 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 05 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 06 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 07 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 08 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 09 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 10 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 11 LIMIT 1), (SELECT min(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 12 LIMIT 1)"
            + "FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y
            + "  UNION"
            + "  SELECT 'Въведени', Station, strftime('%Y',Dat), 'СР', (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 01), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 02), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 03), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 04), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 05), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 06), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 07), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 08), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 09), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 10), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 11), (SELECT vkolsre FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 12)"
            + "FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y
            + "  UNION"
            + "  SELECT 'Изчислени', Station, strftime('%Y',Dat), 'СР', (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 01 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 02 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 03 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 04 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 05 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 06 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 07 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 08 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 09 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 10 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 11 LIMIT 1), (SELECT avg(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 12 LIMIT 1)"
            + "FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y
            + "  UNION"
            + "  SELECT 'Въведени', Station, strftime('%Y',Dat), 'НГ', (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 01), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 02), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 3), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 04), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 05), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 06), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 07), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 08), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 09), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 10), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 11), (SELECT vkolmax FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 12)"
            + "FROM hydmes WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y
            + "  UNION"
            + "  SELECT 'Изчислени', Station, strftime('%Y',Dat), 'НГ', (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 01 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 02 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 03 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 04 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 05 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 06 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 07 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 08 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 09 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 10 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 11 LIMIT 1), (SELECT max(vkol) FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " and strftime('%m',Dat) = 12 LIMIT 1)"
            + "FROM hyddnev WHERE Station = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' and strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y;
        }
        command3 += "  group by strftime('%Y',Dat)";

        SQLiteDataAdapter insertDat3 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command3, Connection);
            using (DataTable dt3 = new DataTable())
            {
                insertDat3.Fill(dt3);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt3.DefaultView;
            }

        }
```

Error is:

> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x80004005): SQL logic error or missing database near "strftime": syntax error

I have the same application who work with MySql database and just copy this query from other application but SQLite syntax is different than MySQL ?

I don't know where and how I can fix the query.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve]? I consider that to include a `.dump` (from sqlite command line tool) of a toy database in which the query (when fixed) demonstrates what you want to achieve. Also a SQL-only query should be part of it.

Comment: So can you help me or no ?

Comment: why don't you split your query and try to debug by executing one by one, it will help to track the problem.

Comment: I think I might be able to help. But without an mcve it would be taking unneccessary effort. If you want my help, please come half the way. Also, I have seen answers downvoted because somebody considers the question bad or offtopic. Not providing a mcve might be the thing which triggers that opinion on your question. An upvote on my request for mcve and a separate comment (which I consider also mcve-related) seem to indicate that others agree. If you describe your problems with making an mcve I might advise on that, too.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to use parameterized querties instead of concatenating strings, unless you want to risk SQL Injection.

Comment: I will do that, but the querry still not running :(

Comment: try to run in debug mode and look at the complete query - put a breakpoint on `SQLiteDataAdapter insertDat3 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command3, Connection);` and check the query you send. It's going to be much easier to find errors this way.

Comment: Please check `strftime('%Y',Dat) = " + y + " strftime('%m',Dat)=04`, you have missing the `and`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet so I'll post this as an answer.

First, I agree with the comments above. It's hard to help you with your problem with just the sample code you provided. Second, don't directly concatenate strings to your queries because there's a risk of SQL injection.

With that being said, I've had a few situations like this myself and my approach is to debug/test my queries directly in a query window. I suggest that you separate your queries, "joined" by those UNIONs, provide actual values to them and run them one by one. If all works fine, run the queries altogether. If everything works, then the problem must be in your concatenation. I always like to approach my problem the "divide-and-conquer" way, I like to separate and eliminate possible causes.

Comment: Please understand that writing what should be a comment into an answer, if you do not have the priviledge for comments yet, is frowned upon in StackOverflow. Be careful. But on the other hand, and to protect you against downvotes: I consider this to actually be a (somewhat brave) answer. It matches a StackOverflow concept to offer some insights and steps towards solution, without necessariy giving the full solution.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I was just trying to contribute. I will keep this in mind the next time I put an answer.